# how do i get rid of these top links in a google map embed?

Tags: google-maps, iframe

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=las+vegas&amp;aq=&amp;sll=37.0625,-95.677068&amp;sspn=59.337006,87.275391&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Las+Vegas,+Clark,+Nevada&amp;z=11&amp;ll=36.114646,-115.172816&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

That code produces a map with links on top for the various viewing modes such as map, satellite, terrain, and earth. Is there a way to get rid of these links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Google Maps API v3, you can set mapTypeControl to false in the MapOptions passed to the Map constructor, e.g.:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
        {center:new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),
         mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
         zoom:initialZoom,
         mapTypeControl:false});
```

Setting that up is more involved than just plugging the URL into an iframe of course, but you get a lot more flexibility.